# Error with subtraction operation in python

Tags: python, subtraction

i trying to do subtraction. so here my command in python:

```
import math
cen = find_centroid(im, 1)
diff = cen-320
print diff
```

but error come out like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test7.py", line 26, in <module>
diff = cen-320
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, `find_centroid` returns a tuple.

Change subtraction expression accordingly:

```
cen[0] - 320
```

Or change the function to return a number instead of a tuple.

Comment: @Floris, For example, `cen[0]` returns the first item of the tuple; `cen[0] - 320` returns the first item subtracted 320.

Comment: Ah - I somehow thought that `cen[..]` might be a syntax I didn't know (similar to `bash`'s `{1..5}` for example). I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you all you need to know:

The result of `find_centroids` is a `tuple` - in Python those are written as (a,b,)

You can't subtract a number from a tuple. But you could do

```
diff = [x - 320 for x in cen]
```

This is called a "list comprehension". It says "evaluate `x - 320` for every value of `x` that you find in `cen`, and return the values as a list in `diff`

Example:

```
>>> cen = (456,234,)
>>> diff = [x - 320 for x in cen]
>>> diff
[136, -86]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is exactly what it says it is. You are trying to subtract an integer from a tuple. From looking at the code, cen must be the tuple because 320 is an integer. This means that find_centriod returns a tuple. This makes sense because a centroid will contain an x and a y coordinate.

If you only want the x coordinate, you can use cen[0]. If you only want the y coordinate, you can use cen[1].

Comment: It might be worth reading http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/. The title makes it sound intimidating, but it's not. Keep at it!